# Second monitor works only if plugged after SDDM started

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, kde, external-monitor

I cannot make my second monitor work properly with an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation. This is the behavior:

1. If I start the laptop with the external monitor disconnected/powered-off, I can easily boot it up and login to KDE. Then, I simply attach/power-on it and KDE switches on a beautiful dual-head environment.
2. If I start the laptop with the external monitor connected/powered-on, I get a blank screen on both of them (in the laptop monitor and the external one) and the only way I have to resume the situation is CTRL+ALT+F1 and get the console to reboot the system (even restarting sddm does not change a thing).

Some details:

- Laptop: ASUS N552VW-FI202T with nVidia GeForce GTX 960M video card
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (kernel 4.4.0-62-generic)
- nVidia drivers: 378.09

I couldn't find useful logs to show (which is why I'm not figuring the problem out maybe). The sddm service is working great according to systemctl and in the Xorg logs I just see the following error (that I don't understand fully):

```
(EE) modeset(G0): failed to set mode: Invalid argument
```

It's driving me crazy, I've googled a lot before choosing to write here :)

Thanks guys.